# Binding MVC grid to stored procedure with large amount of data

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik, grid

## Binding MVC grid to stored procedure with large amount of data:

I want to bind MVC grid to an object result that returned from SP

Normally the grid request only data needed to be shown to the user and that will be very good when binding to a table with large amount of data that lets the grid fast and its performance would be good.

i have 2 ways to bind MVC grid with SP:

1. Bind to SP without using `.ToList()` it gives me an error "The result of a query can not be enumerated more than once."
2. Bind to sp using `.ToList()` will resolve that error but it will loads all records from database first and the performance will be bad and the grid loading, paging, sorting and filtering would be very slow.

Please tell me a solution to bind MVC grid with SP that returns large amount of data with good performance.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have used jqgrid in the past, jqgrid implements paging so not all the content of the grid is actually displayed at once, you pick the number of rows per page and jqgrid automatically will hook the navigation to your controller. There are a lot of examples of this on the web. If you click the next page it will retrieve the appropriate data for that page and so forth.

The jqgrid page has a lot of examples in loading data that ilustrate this: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, here is another page that talks how that is implemented at the server side using mvc http://www.codersource.net/AspNet/ASPNetAdvanced/jqGridPaginginaspnetmvc.aspx, I'm sure if you look around you'll find a lot of information on how to go about this approach.

Finally I usually avoid showing the user a lot of data anyways, mainly because it is hard for a human been to make any sense of more than 100 rows of data having a way to search further in it. So I rather try and attempt to shrink the data size giving them a way to filter it down further, but this is not always possible.

Hope this helps.